# How to load images using loadImage the function

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am using jboss application server for deploying my app containing processing code.

My directory structure looks like this
myapp-war-1.0.0.war\js\processing.js
myapp-war-1.0.0.war\img\bird.png
myapp-ear-1.0.0\myapp-war-1.0.0.war\birds\bird.html

How to refer the image bird.png from bird.html

```
<script>
PImage img;
img =  loadImage("img\bird.png");
// The above code doesn't seem to work, but If I use an absolute path to a file in the file system, the processing IDE is able to pick it up.
image(img, 10, 10);
...
```

How should I look for this file in a relative fashion within my Java EE application packed in a EAR format.

Comment: Try to use a url instead of a filepath

Answer (score 1):

you can try solve this by looking at the output of:

`var jsCode = Processing.compile(txt).sourceCode;`
`alert(jsCode);`

where txt is the processing script code !